# How do we handle Cursors in Android?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, cursor

[Android Cursor Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409864/android-cursor-problem)

I was reading this question and one of answer suggest that we should parse useful data regarding than parsing the whole `Cursors`.

Will this be applicable in the cursor if I were to parse a `Cursors` into a `ListAdapter`?

Comment: Here is the simple answer: https://queception.com/question.php?question=106

Answer (score 1):

I would not parse a `Cursor` into a `ListAdapter`.  I would instead use a [`CursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) for binding data to a `ListView`.

Comment: haushchild sorry i was actually referring to BaseAdapter, does it make any difference then?

Comment: You should use a `CursorAdapter` over a `BaseAdapter`.  A `CursorAdapter` is meant to bind a `Cursor`'s data to a `ListView`

Comment: Here is the simple answer: https://queception.com/question.php?question=106

Answer (score 0):

I think what you said is correct.

**Best choice**: only query columns from DB that you actually need, i.e. using

```
db.query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
```

**OK choice**: do select * but only query the values you actually need from the cursor

Obviously, every operation takes some time, so if you're querying hundreds or thousands of DB records, it's better to do it efficiently!

Comment: thanks for your reply. but my doubt is that should we parse a cursor into the listadapter like MyListAdapter my_adapter = new MyListAdapter(context, cursor); or take out information you need and parse in array list?